# My handleChange method of simple react todoapp is not doing what it needs to do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

In the output, Only the default completed values are checked! not able change the checks of tasks.

These are my Java script files

`app.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: Todosdata
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const udpated = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })

      return {
        todos: udpated
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const todoelements = this.state.todos.map(item => <ToDoItem key={item.id}
      todoitem={item}
      handleChange={this.handleChange} />)

    return (
      <div className="App">
        < div className="todo-list" >
          {todoelements}
        </div >
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`ToDoItem.js`

```
const ToDoItem = (props) => {
    const Afterstyle = {
        fontColor: "red",
        textDecoration: "line-through"
    }

    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input type="checkbox"
                checked ={props.todoitem.completed}
                onChange ={() => props.handleChange(props.todoitem.id)} />
            <p style={props.todoitem.completed ? Afterstyle : null}>{props.todoitem.task}</p>
        </div>
   )
}
```

i did console log inside if condition of handle Change method,its printing 2 times.
I am stuck at this for hours please fix this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mutating the `todo` item instead of creating a new one. Change your handler like that:

```
handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const udpated = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                // if the id matches return a new object
                return {...todo, completed: !todo.completed};
            }
        
            return todo
        });

        return {todos: udpated};
    }
}
```

Live Demo:

[image: Edit compassionate-architecture-kzsu2]

Comment: Thanks!Can you explain me why i should use new one? because in freecodecamp tutorial he did same thing as i previously did, but it worked there!